# Single Schengen Visa Entrance

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a schengen visa for single entrance. My itinerary shows that My first entry country will be Italy. 
At the same time, on my visa there is no country restriction written.

My plans have changed a little after issuing visa and I will travel to my destination through Barcelona with connection of 4 hrs. So technically it turns out that my first entry will be to Spain.

I would like to know if this will cause any issues? Is it ok or not?